# CMake can not find LAPACK library on windows

Tags: winapi, cmake, lapack, blas

I'm trying to build a C++ project using **CMake** which includes **LAPACK library** on a **win32** system.

Following the documentary [LAPACK for windows](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries_mingw),

I installed MinGW 32 bits and added "C:\MinGW\bin" in the path, 
then put downloaded pre-built libraries: libblas.lib, libblas.dll, liblapack.lib, liblapack.dll in the path
"\projectRoot\3rdparty\LAPACK"

The structure of folders is as below:

```
\projectRoot
    \CMakeLists.txt
    \3rdparty
         \LAPACK
             libblas.lib
             ...
```

in the CMakeLists file, I added

```
set(LAPACK_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/LAPACK")
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
```

but got error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:810 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:197 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
```

and before the error, there's something that CMake couldn't find

```
Looking for sgemm_
Looking for sgemm_ - not found
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE
```

I can't figure out what's the cause of the problem.

Thank you in advance if you could share your experience.

Comment: The BLAS and LAPACK packages are separate, and must be found and linked individually. From your linked instructions: "*Link your C application built with MSVC with the BLAS and LAPACK libraries...*". You haven't shown your entire CMake file, but did you also call `find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)` before finding LAPACK?

Comment: @squareskittles Thank you. So I tried added `set(BLAS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/LAPACK")` and `find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)` but still got the same error

Comment: I was thinking maybe it's caused by the prefix of the libraries I downloaded. So I added `set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "lib")`, but didn't work neither...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question.

Finally what I did to find the package was:

Copy a built version from [jlblancoc/suitesparse-metis-for-windows](https://github.com/jlblancoc/suitesparse-metis-for-windows/tree/master/lapack_windows),
then use config mode of find_package by

```
set(LAPACK_DIR "dir/to/lapacklibs")
find_package(LAPACK CONFIG REQUIRED)
```