# CMake can't find BLAS on MSYS2

Tags: cmake, mingw-w64, blas, msys2, openblas

I am trying to compile [this software](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem) in the MSYS2 environment on Windows. This is the line looking for the packages:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(BLAS REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(LAPACK REQUIRED)
SET(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES} ${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
```

I have installed the BLAS/LAPACK dependencies using

```
pacman -S make msys/cmake msys/gcc-fortran mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-openblas64
```

but I get the error messages:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22.1/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:1337 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:403 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

You may find the modified `CMakeLists.txt` file [here](https://pastebin.com/YtT81NVv) (I have commented out all the MPI, MMG, MKL, and APPLE-related entries), and the complete output can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/NjtRfamu).

I can probably specify the locations explicitly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62517291/4999991) and [here](http://www.elmerfem.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=20993&sid=98a8a0604e47c45e50a3e65ee9277c88#p20993)

```
SET(BLAS_LIBRARIES /c/tools/msys64/mingw64/lib/libopenblas_64.a)
SET(LAPACK_LIBRARIES /c/tools/msys64/mingw64/lib/libopenblas_64.a)
```

but I want CMake to find these dependencies automatically. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the canonical way to get BLAS/LAPACK libraries installed under MSYS2 and get CMAKE to find them automatically with the `FIND_PACKAGE()` functions or otherwise.

Comment: It seems you're inconsistently using two different [MSYS2 environments](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/): MSYS and MINGW64. The latter should be preferred. Uninstall `cmake` and `gcc-fortran` and replace them with the packages prefixed by `mingw-w64-x86_64-`. Restart your MSYS2 terminal using `mingw64.exe` to get that compiler in PATH; if done correctly, the terminal prompt should say `MINGW64` in magenta letters.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are actually right. I did notice that I was using the wrong `mingw64.exe` environment initially. Will edit the post and add the new information. But I have to use the `msys2.exe` environment and packages because of the issues explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798994/4999991).

Comment: Can you elaborate why that behavior is a problem?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is a cross-platform software. I need to specify some instructions explicitly for the MSYS2 environment. If you check the other post, you can see the train of issues I have had with the `mingw64.exe` environment (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60747538/4999991)).

Comment: Decent software should support all (or most) of those environments. If a library I was going to use worked only on MSYS and not MINGW64, I'd just take a different library.

Comment: The detection method I use is `uname -o` == `Msys`. Works in all of those environments, I believe.