# How to install LAPACK for Fortran on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I'm trying to use LAPACK in a Fortran project, but I can't get CMake to find my LAPACK dll. I have very little experience with Fortran, Cmake and linking dll's. I use [this](https://github.com/SethMMorton/cmake_fortran_template) template for my project. In the main CMakeLists.txt file, I enabled the option

`INCLUDE(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/SetUpLAPACK.cmake)`

but I get the following error

> Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)

when trying to compile the project. I have tried to put the **libblas.dll** and **liblapack.dll** (I got them from [this](https://icl.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries_mingw) website) in different folders which are on in the PATH. I also tried putting them directly in the folder where the executables should be generated, but I still get the same error.

So my question is: How can I properly install LAPACK on my system, so that the compiler can find it and successfully compile the project?

I use gfortran (MinGW64) and Windows 10/11.

Answer (score 4):

Best/easiest option AFAICT is to replace MinGW64 with [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/),
then you can just install lapack with it's package manager:

```
pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-lapack
```

(you should be able to install the MSYS2 gcc/gfortran toolchain as its dependency):  the library will be placed in MSYS's shared library folder.

Otherwise, most likely you'll have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did this, but I still get the same error. Do I have to somehow tell CMake, that I want to use the Compiler installed using MSYS2? I tried using the SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER) command, but it didn't work for me

Comment: based on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408657/cmake-can-not-find-lapack-library-on-windows)[this answer] you may try manually setting the lapack directory to MSYS2's lib (something like `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib`)

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I don't get the Blas not found error anymore, but instead while building the project it says, that "dgesv" is not recognized (dgesv is a Lapack function). I tried uninstalling all fortran compilers on my system and reinstalling it using MSYS2, but now I get the error: 

CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Fortran_PREPROCESS_SOURCE